# Slow distinct query in SQL Server over large dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

We're using SQL Server 2005 to track a fair amount of constantly incoming data (5-15 updates per second). We noticed after it has been in production for a couple months that one of the tables has started to take an obscene amount of time to query.

The table has 3 columns:

- `id` -- autonumber (clustered)
- `typeUUID` -- GUID generated before the insert happens; used to group the types together
- `typeName` -- The type name (duh...)

One of the queries we run is a distinct on the `typeName` field:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [typeName] FROM [types] WITH (nolock);
```

The `typeName` field has a non-clusted, non-unique ascending index on it. The table contains approximately 200M records at the moment. When we run this query, the query took 5m 58s to return! Perhaps we're not understanding how the indexes work... But I didn't think we mis-understood them *that* much.

To test this a little further, we ran the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [typeName] FROM (SELECT TOP 1000000 [typeName] FROM [types] WITH (nolock)) AS [subtbl]
```

This query returns in about 10 seconds, as I would expect, it's scanning the table.

Is there something we're missing here? Why does the first query take so long?

**Edit:** Ah, my apologies, the first query returns 76 records, thank you ninesided.

**Follow up:** Thank you all for your answers, it makes more sense to me now (I don't know why it didn't before...). Without an index, it's doing a table scan across 200M rows, with an index, it's doing an index scan across 200M rows...

SQL Server does prefer the index, and it does give a little bit of a performance boost, but nothing to be excited about. Rebuilding the index did take the query time down to just over 3m instead of 6m, an improvement, but not enough. I'm just going to recommend to my boss that we normalize the table structure.

Once again, thank you all for your help!!

Comment: how many distinct types do you typically expect?

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like your design is fundamentally flawed. 200M records in an "incoming" table? Can't you shove them somewhere else after they've been around awhile? It's tough to give better advice without understanding your application, but it sounds like you may need some serious refactoring.

Comment: Yes, we do have a lot of data we're dealing with, currently that is 4 months worth of data. We're going to need to partition the data, but we haven't gotten there yet.

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking of what a typeUUID column might actually be useful for... combine that with a one-column index of cardinality 76 on 200M rows, 20 inserts/sec, and claimed "performance problems", and that adds up to "back to the drawing board" in my mind :(

Comment: >>But the difference should be reversed, because the first 
>>query is using an index

NO - it's not. If you scan for ALL rows to a DISTINCT on them, you'll ALWAYS have a full table scan - no index is going to help with that.

Comment: No, you can do a full index scan to resolve this query; you look through every entry in the index and count how many are distinct. But that ignores many of the benefits of the index's structure, and is not going to have much better performance than a plain sequential scan.

Comment: We're storing positional data for a couple thousand vehicles (thus the volume). Each vehicle has several types associated with it, but were stored in the table this way to reduce storage (it was a larger concern at the time).

Comment: As for the performance problems, they also stem from the desire for reduced storage much more so than the schema itself. Before each record is inserted, the previous record is queried so that it can be compared to the new record before it is inserted.

Comment: I see; that makes sense. The original schema designer went for "size" in the classic size-versus-speed tradeoff (questionable to me, what with storage as cheap as it is these days) and now *you* have to deal with the schema and pay the price. Good luck making the best of this situation :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I was the one that originally designed the schema. But I was given the space requirement, that part wasn't my decision... But now that requirement is being relaxed and I'm being told I have to fix it without losing data or going offline.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do misunderstand the index.  Even if it did use the index it would still do an index scan across 200M entries.  This is going to take a long time, plus the time it takes to do the DISTINCT (causes a sort) and it's a bad thing to run.  Seeing a DISTINCT in a query always raises a red flag and causes me to double check the query.  In this case, perhaps you have a normalization issue?

Comment: No doubt, this is partially a data normalization issue, but we're already having performance problems from normalizing the data before. We're barely staying ahead of the incoming data as it is.

Comment: It is an index scan, but shouldn't scanning the index (at least in this case) only hit the tree's nodes, not scan through the leafs?

Comment: The index could be heavily fragmented, increasing the scan time.  Do you run any maintenance jobs?  You should be doing that nightly with that much data. (Assuming you can schedule the time.)

Comment: Hmm... that's a good point. We don't currently do maintenance like that, but you are correct, that much data should have nightly maintenance. I'll have to try that tomorrow.

Comment: Exactly - the index will help if a query like "WHERE typename = xyz" is made - but for a select distinct * from ... the index won't help at all. if you have 200 M rows, all 200 M rows will have to be scanned.....

Answer (score 5):

There is an issue with the SQL Server optimizer when using the `DISTINCT` keyword. The solution was to force it to keep the same query plan by breaking out the distinct query separately.

So we took queries such as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [typeName] FROM [types] WITH (nolock);
```

and break it up into the following:

```
SELECT typeName INTO #tempTable1 FROM types WITH (NOLOCK)
SELECT DISTINCT typeName FROM #tempTable1
```

Another way to get around it is to use a `GROUP BY`, which gets a different optimization plan.

Comment: It might be good to add some more information about how this changes the execution plan.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt SQL Server will even try to use the index, it'd have to do practically the same amount of work (given the narrow table), reading all 200M rows regardless of whether it looks at the table or the index. If the index on `typeName` was clustered it may reduce the time taken as it shouldn't need to sort before grouping.

If the cardinality of your types is low, how about maintaining a summary table which holds the list of distinct `type` values? A trigger on insert/update of the main table would do a check on the summary table and insert a new record when a new type is found.

Comment: +1; trigger on insert is better than what I was thinking of (add a second INSERT after the main, inserting into said summary table, and catching/ignoring UNIQUE constraint violation).

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing.  Do the summary table if you need to run the distinct query often. You'll also need to add a DELETE trigger to clean up the table after you remove rows. Or if not a big deal, schedule a SQL Job to update the summary table nightly. (removing deleted types.)

Comment: An idea if DELETEs are involved: have the summary table have a reference count column; triggers on INSERT increment it and on DELETE decrement it. That should work pretty nicely.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed out - when you do a SELECT DISTINCT (typename) over your table, you'll end up with a full table scan no matter what.

So it's really a matter of limiting the number of rows that need to be scanned.

The question is: what do you need your DISTINCT typenames for? And how many of your 200M rows are distinct? Do you have only a handful (a few hundred at most) distinct typenames??

If so - you could have a separate table DISTINCT_TYPENAMES or something and fill those initially by doing a full table scan, and then on inserting new rows to the main table, just always check whether their typename is already in DISTINCT_TYPENAMES, and if not, add it.

That way, you'd have a separate, small table with just the distinct TypeName entries, which would be lightning fast to query and/or to display.

Marc

Comment: It is a index scan, not a table scan (I already verified this). It was my understanding that if the index is built correctly, it would simply scan the index, rather than the entire table.

Comment: It can and does scan the index instead of the table. But this is not the problem indexes are designed to solve, and so a full index scan cannot resolve this query significantly faster than a full table scan.

Comment: And in this case, the non-clustered index will already contain two of the fields (the "typeName" and the "id" for the actual lookup), so the non-clustered index is almost the whole table anyway...

Answer (score 2):

A looping approach should use multiple seeks (but loses some parallelism). It might be worth a try for cases with relatively few distinct values compared to the total number of rows (low cardinality).

Idea was from this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96364):

```
select typeName into #Result from Types where 1=0;

declare @t varchar(100) = (select min(typeName) from Types);
while @t is not null
begin
    set @t = (select top 1 typeName from Types where typeName > @t order by typeName);    
    if (@t is not null)
        insert into #Result values (@t);
end

select * from #Result;
```

And looks like there are also some other methods (notably the recursive CTE @Paul White):

[different-ways-to-find-distinct-values-faster-methods](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/18252/different-ways-to-find-distinct-values-faster-methods.aspx)

[sqlservercentral Topic873124-338-5](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic873124-338-5.aspx#bm1013407)

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is statistics. To find last updated:

```
SELECT
    name AS index_name, 
    STATS_DATE(object_id, index_id) AS statistics_update_date
FROM
    sys.indexes 
WHERE
    object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyTable');
```

Edit: Stats are updated when indexes are rebuilt, which I see are not maintained

My second thought is that is the index still there? The TOP query should still use an index.
I've just tested on one of my tables with 57 million rows and both use the index.

Comment: Yes, the index is there, and it is using the index. :( That was the first thing I checked. It's scanning the index, but I don't know why scanning the index's only field should take so long...

Answer (score 1):

I could be missing something but would it be more efficient if an overhead on load to create a view with distinct values and query that instead?

This would give almost instant responses to the select if the result set is significantly smaller with the overhead over populating it on each write though given the nature of the view that might be trivial in itself.

It does ask the question how many writes compared to how often you want the distinct and the importance of the speed when you do.

Comment: materialized view, or depending of the app, a plain table with distinct, populated every time you insert a value (by your code, or with a stored procedure, either called by your code or by a trigger on INSERT)

Answer (score 1):

An indexed view can make this faster.

```
create view alltypes
with schemabinding as
select typename, count_big(*) as kount
from dbo.types
group by typename

create unique clustered index idx
on alltypes (typename)
```

The work to keep the view up to date on each change to the base table should be moderate (depending on your application, of course -- my point is that it doesn't have to scan the whole table each time or do anything insanely expensive like that.)

Alternatively you could make a small table holding all values:

```
select distinct typename
into alltypes
from types

alter table alltypes
add primary key (typename)

alter table types add foreign key (typename) references alltypes
```

The foreign key will make sure that all values used appear in the parent `alltypes` table.  The trouble is in ensuring that `alltypes` does *not* contain values not used in the child `types` table.

Answer (score 0):

I should try something like this:

```
SELECT typeName FROM [types] WITH (nolock)
group by typeName;
```

And like other i would say you need to normalize that column.

Answer (score 0):

An index helps you quickly find a row.  But you're asking the database to list all unique types for the entire table.  An index can't help with that.

You could run a nightly job which runs the query and stores it in a different table.  If you require up-to-date data, you could store the last ID included in the nightly scan, and combine the results:

```
select type
from nightlyscan
union
select distinct type
from verybigtable
where rowid > lastscannedid
```

Another option is to normalize the big table into two tables:

```
talbe1: id, guid, typeid
type table: typeid, typename
```

This would be very beneficial if the number of types was relatively small.