# Recommended database type to handle billion of records

Tags: database, performance, sql-server-2008, scalability

I started to work in a project which must reuse a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 old database that has a table with more than 7,000,000 records.

Queries to that table last minutes and I was wondering if a different type of database (i.e. not relational) would be better to handle this.

What do you recommend? In any case, is there a way to improve the performance of a relational database?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I am using Navicat to perform this simple query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [NROCAJA]
FROM [CAJASE]
```

so complex stuff and subqueries are not a problem. I was also wondering if a lack of indexes was the problem, but the table seems to be indexed:

[image: Index description of CAJASE table]

**EPIC FAIL:**

The database was in a remote server!! The query actually takes 5 seconds (I still think it's much time, but now the issue is different). 99% of elapsed time was network transfer. Thanks for your answers anyway :)

Comment: 7M records isn't all that many - if you can provide more info, we can look at indices, plans etc.

Comment: This is WAY too generic to be answerable.  However, SQL Server handles billion record tables fine if they are constructed properly.  I'm guessing you don't have proper indexes to start.

Comment: @elitalon - Following your edit how many `DISTINCT` values are there for `NROCAJA` in the 7,000,000 row table? If there are relatively few then there is a trick that can be used to optimise this using a recursive CTE, or you could use an indexed view ([related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5973850/73226)), If there are lots it could well be a network issue pushing back the data.

Comment: Also do you have concurrent data modifications happening on that table? Your select queries may be encountering blocking. Or maybe you don't have enough RAM and the data needs to be brought in from disc each time you need to find the bottleneck. I suggest reading a book on performance tuning.

Comment: @Martin Smith Most of the 7 million records are distinct. BTW, the query lasted 805 seconds. My computer has 4GB RAM.

Comment: How long does `SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT [NROCAJA]) FROM [CAJASE]` take? That will do the same work but eliminate most of the network traffic. Also if that still takes a long time try `SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT [NROCAJA]) FROM [CAJASE] WITH (NOLOCK)` to see if blocking might be the culprit.

Comment: The first one lasts 1.948s, while the `NOLOCK` flavor takes 1.680s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profile your queries - 7 million records isn't that great a number, so chances are you're missing an index or performing complex sub-queries that are not performing well as the dataset scales.

I don't think you need to re-architect the entire system yet.

Answer (score 3):

7 million is a tiny database for SQL Server, it easily handles terrabytes of data with proper design. Likely you have a poor design combined with missing indexes combined with poor hardware, combined with badly performing queries.  Don't blame the incompetence of your database developers on SQL Server.

Comment: I am not blaming SQL Server at all, it was just extra information on what I've been told to use. Also, I was asking for alternatives to relational databases in general not to specific engines :)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are selecting "distinct" could be a problem. Maybe move those distinct value into it's own table to avoid duplication.